# Option title of attribute is showing

Tags: magento-1.9

I am facing a problem with a new store. On the product page it shows above the options field (also in configurable product) the name: SIZE. I need to remove that. Does someone know where i do that?

Thank you

[image: SIZE]

Answer (score 0):

You could go and add some css

```
.product-options dt {display: none;}
```

Or something similar.